# Mixing HAVING with CASE OR Analytic functions in MySQL (PartitionQualify(?

Tags: mysql, having, window-functions

I have a SELECT query that returns some fields like this:

```
Date | Campaign_Name | Type | Count_People
Oct  | Cats          | 1    | 500
Oct  | Cats          | 2    | 50
Oct  | Dogs          | 1    | 80
Oct  | Dogs          | 2    | 50
```

The query uses aggregation and I only want to include results where when Type = 1 then ensure that the corresponding Count_People is greater than 99.

Using the example table, I'd like to have two rows returned: Cats. Where Dogs is type 1 it's excluded because it's below 100, in this case where Dogs = 2 should be excluded also.

Put another way, if type = 1 is less than 100 then remove all records of the corresponding campaign name.

I started out trying this:

```
HAVING CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT Count_People) > 99 END
```

I used Teradata earlier int he year and remember working on a query that used an analytic function "Qualify PartitionBy". I suspect something along those lines is what I need? I need to base the exclusion on aggregation before the query is run?

How would I do this in MySQL? Am I making sense?

Comment: MySQL does not have window functions (aka "analytic functions"). So you will need to find a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand the question, I think your best bet will be a subquery to determine which date/campaign combinations of a type=1 have a count_people greater than 99.

```
SELECT
    <table>.date,
    <table>.campaign_name,
    <table>.type,
    count(distinct count_people) as count_people    
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date,
            campaign_name           
        FROM
            <table>
        WHERE type=1
        HAVING count(distinct count_people) > 99
        GROUP BY 1,2
    ) type1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN <table> ON
        type1.campaign_name = <table>.campaign_name AND
        type1.date = <table>.date
WHERE <table>.type IN (1,2)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

The subquery here only returns campaign/date combinations when both the type=1 AND it has greater than 99 count_people. It uses a LEFT JOIN back to the  to insure that only those campaign/date combinations make it into the result set.

The WHERE on the main query keeps the results to only Types 1 and 2, which you stated was already a filter in place (though not mentioned in the question, it was stated in a comment to a previous answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to answer by @JNevill I think you will have no option but to use subselects to pre-filter the record set you are dealing with, as working with `HAVING` is going to limit you only to the current record being evaluated - there is no way to compare against previous or subsequent records in the set in this manner.

So have a look at something like this:

```
SELECT
    full_data.date AS date,
    full_data.campaign_name AS campaign_name,
    full_data.type AS type,
    COUNT(full_data.people) AS people_count
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date,
            campaign_name,
            type,
            COUNT(people) AS people_count
        FROM table
        WHERE type IN (1,2)
        GROUP BY date, campaign_name, type
    ) AS full_data   
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            date,
            campaign_name,
            COUNT(people) AS people_count
        FROM table
        WHERE type = 1
        GROUP BY date, campaign_name
        HAVING people_count < 100
    ) AS filter
ON
    full_data.date = filter.date
    AND full_data.campaign_name = filter.campaign_name
WHERE
    filter.date IS NULL
    AND filter.campaign_name IS NULL
```

The first subselect is basically your current query without any attempt at using `HAVING` to filter out results.  The second subselect is used to find all date/campaign name combos which have `people_count`  > 100 and use those as a filter for against the full data set.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the answer from @JNevill while typing this up.  This is same basic concept, just with slightly different semantics. I use a NULL filter instead of a positive one.